# How to use Umlauts (äüö) in axis label with knitr, LuaTex and tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, r, knitr

When compiling pdf documents with complex tikz figures using knitr, the pdftex engine would sometimes run out of memory. Thus, I used the luatex engine to compile these Rnw files. However, I am not able to include Umlauts (äüö) in my plots this way. Please see the example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
<<pdftexGood, dev="tikz", message=FALSE, echo=FALSE, cache=FALSE>>=
options(tikzDefaultEngine = "pdftex")
plot(rnorm(100), xlab="Der satanarchäolügenialkohöllische Wunschpunsch")
@
<<luatexBad, dev="tikz", message=FALSE, echo=FALSE, cache=FALSE, eval=FALSE>>=
options(tikzDefaultEngine = "luatex")
plot(rnorm(100), xlab="Der satanarchäolügenialkohöllische Wunschpunsch")
@
\end{document}
```

When changing eval=TRUE in the luatex chunk, I get an "Error in getMetricsFromLatex(TeXMetrics)".

What can I do to resolve the issue? Thanks!

Comment: Load the fontspec package and remove inputenc when using luatex (but I don't know if this related to your problem).

Comment: Thanks @ulrike, this pointed me to the right direction and was able to resolve the issue. I'll write up an answer to myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Ulrike Fischer's comment, I was able to resolve the issue myself. Using RStudio as an editor, it turns out that the Rnw file was still compiled using pdftex. Thus, the luatex-chunk needed a different package to be used compared to the pdftex-document (inputenc vs fontspec).

As I was not able to set luatex as a compiler in RStudio, I used XeLaTex and adapted the packages. Now, I can compile the luatex-chunk just fine. The fact that the pdftex-chunk won't compile anymore (for the above mentioned package problems) is no problem for me.

```
% !TeX program = XeLaTeX
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
<<pdftexBad, dev="tikz", message=FALSE, echo=FALSE, cache=FALSE>>=
#options(tikzDefaultEngine = "pdftex")
#plot(rnorm(100), xlab="Der satanarchäolügenialkohöllische Wunschpunsch")
@
<<luatexGood, dev="tikz", message=FALSE, echo=FALSE, cache=FALSE, eval=TRUE>>=
options(tikzDefaultEngine = "luatex")
plot(rnorm(100), xlab="Der satanarchäolügenialkohöllische Wunschpunsch")
@
\end{document}
```